# decode sh256 in oracle

Tags: encryption, plsql, oracle12c

I want to decode the below hash value to text.

bb37497f9b8cdcccf20ff6eee342bc1f76f72f35a7305af28a81b75d3967ea2f.

I tried below function but gives me the output in special characters

```
select UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR('bb37497f9b8cdcccf20ff6eee342bc1f76f72f35a7305af28a81b75d3967ea2f', 'AL32UTF8') from dual;
```

output

```
�7I����v�0Z]9g
```

any other function would give me the text value?

Comment: What are you expecting from your "decoding"? The hash value is a hex-string encoding of a byte array that holds the SHA256-hash. If you should try to retrieve the data back from which this value is created - sorry my fried thats not possible as hash-function are "one way functions".

Comment: https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/

Comment: Yes Michael you are right , I want to retrieve the data back from this value. So its one way function I got it .. Is it possible to decrypt AES encryption ?

Comment: @kashi: "Is it possible to decrypt AES encryption ?" - yes because its **encryption**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash functions are deliberately one way. So you cannot get the original value from the hash value. (You could use brute force and hash all possible original values and see which yields the given hash value. But that's likely not finishing in your lifetime and will produce false positives because of collisions. So you'd even need some second criteria.) Not in Oracle, not anywhere else...